# PyAutoGui locateOnScreen Loop

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've been trying to create a loop where it looks for an image, and if not found scrolls once then tries again until it finds it. Problem is, when it finds it, it doesn't break. I can't figure out why it isnt breaking. Its returns none each scroll, until it finds the image and it returns a location, but once it returns the location it just keeps scrolling.

```
false = None
while false is None:
    try:
        none = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('findadobe.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.7)
        time.sleep(1)
        scroll(-2600)
        pyautogui.moveTo(none)
        print(none)
        if false is not None:
            break
    except:
        print(none)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never changing the value of the `false` variable, so it always remains `None`. Also, you're playing with fire by using `false` and `none` as variable names.

This might work a little better:

```
loc = None
while loc is None:
    try:
        loc = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('findadobe.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.7)
        time.sleep(1)
        scroll(-2600)
        pyautogui.moveTo(loc)
        print(none)
        if loc is not None:
            break
    except:
        print(loc)
```